# Gitlab to Azure migration

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a requirement that, I have repository in my Gitlab now i want migration in such a way that if any changes pushed in the Gitlab repository then all the changes should be Reflected in my Azure repo.

i have just try to use pull and push manually

Answer (score 1):

I have just completed the migration of Gitlab.com repositories (not self-hosted) to the Azure DevOps platform. I was using the free tier, so there are some limitations, but this can be done using push mirroring.
I used HTTPS and Personal Access Tokens, but there are a few other options...

1. create an empty repository on Azure DevOps that will be your destination
2. in Azure DevOps for to User settings -> Personal Access Tokens
3. create a new token with at least Code (Read & Write permissions)
4. save the token for later
5. go to Gitlab.com repository, Settings -> Repository -> Mirroring repositories
6. now you need to enter the destination repository URL and PAT and you are good to go... BUT, there is an issue with Gitlab here and the instructions on the web page are wrong for Azure DevOps!!! So...
7. Copy Azure repository URL and then change it. Add the PAT after the username, like this: `https://<username>:<personal_access_token>@dev.azure.com/.../myrepo`
   The URL should NOT contain the ".git" appendix.
8. enter the PAT as password and click "Mirror repository"
9. test operation using sync button below

While gitlab states that syncronization should in instant after every commit, it turns out that free tier is limited to 1 sync every 5 minutes.

*As a side note, I think the URL problem comes from Gitlab using git ls-remote command before the actual push mirroring, that command is missing the PAT.*

[image: Screenshot of Gitlab Mirroring menu]

Answer (score -1):

If you don't like manual method, there is synchronization method between GitLab and Azure. For this you need Azure DevOps CLI. You need to create CI(Continuous Integration) pipeline that will run whenever change is pushed to the GitLab repository. Following is the way of creating CI pipline:

1. Azure DevOps CLI -> install
2. CI pipeline -> creation
3. In Pipeline tab, click New Pipeline button
4. Select Import Git repository
5. Select the ZIP file from GitLab
6. Next -> Save -> Run

Comment: hi @Farkhod Abdukodirov can you provide more details in this like want to know what is the role here for Azure devops cli

Comment: I would suggest to go through the following docs, it helps you to understand general Repository mirroring: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/index.html